# How to reuse dynamically provisioned EBS volumes with AWS EBS CSI driver after recreating EKS cluster?

Tags: aws-ebs-csi-driver

Is there a way to reuse the EBS volumes, that are dynamically provisioned by the AWS EBS CSI driver, after destroying and recreating the EKS cluster? It is not possible to set a static value for the `CSIVolumeName` tag. So, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a direct way due to the reason mentioned in the [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/1451#issuecomment-1323706670). But there is a solution to this. **Solution:** Create a Lambda, that uses AWS SDK to fetch the required dynamically provisioned EBS volumes, that are to be reused, and creates `PersistentVolumes` with `claimRef` using the tags present in the fetched EBS volumes. In this way, the `claimRef` will have the name of the previously created `PersistentVolumeClaim` as its value. And when the `PersistentVolumeClaims` are recreated after EKS cluster recreation, this Lambda gets executed, the `PersistentVolumes` get created, the `PersistentVolumeClaims` are automatically mapped to those `PersistentVolumes` with their names in the `claimRef`.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the lambda and an example of the code?